# how to Write in MATLAB one function, Its inputs are : • Array of only 4 elements (4 pixels)

Tags: arrays, matlab

How to write in `MATLAB` one function, its inputs are:

- Array of only 4 elements (4 pixels)
- The location (x,y) of the
  interpolated pixel relatively to the pixel (0,0)

Its out put is the new intensity of the interpolated pixel. 
Bilinear interpolation.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what exactly is the problem? If you don't know how to get started try `help function` or just try the calculations without building them into a function yet.

Comment: `interp2` already does this...?